# Which tool to use for syntax highlighting using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to do syntax highlighting using vue js :
Have written the below piece of code:However unable to see the message "This is a test ".What am I doing wrong here?.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="app">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    e1:'#app',
    data:{
        message:'This is a test'
    }

})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question? Syntax highlighting, or why this program doesn't work?

Comment: both syntax highlighting using js and why the code does not work

Comment: Please keep it to one question at a time, and concentrate on that one. Preferably the one *not* about 3rd party recommendations.

Comment: sure,since I am novice to vue js ,was curious why code does not work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have a typo there:

```
e1:'#app',
```

should be

```
el:'#app',
```

Comment: Wow, good catch :)

Comment: Thanks ,yep there was a typo this worked.